# Get ComboBox Value From Two Tables

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox, datasource

I have Ttwo Tables:

**TblNum**:

[image: NumID , Number]

**TblMaster**:

[image]

---

`TblMaster` have Relation with `TblNum` with ( **`NumID`** )

I have 1 combobox, and i want to load data values to my combobox, by reading from `TblMaster` and showing `Number` from `TblNum`.

Actually, i use this code on load form:

```
    private void frmOrgChartsManage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load ComboBox Source from MasterTable
        using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            // At first assign properties DisplayMember and ValueMember.
            cmbMaster.DisplayMember = "NumID";
            cmbMaster.ValueMember = "MasterID";

            // And then assign DataSource property of the cmbMaster.
            cmbMaster.DataSource = db.MasterRepository.Get();
        }
    }
```

with this code, i can see in my combobox (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

**Expected Result** :

how i can load `Number01 , Number02 , Number03 , Number04 , Number05` instead of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` in my `DisplayMember`  ?

**EDIT:**
I need get data value from `TblMaster` and see name from `TblNum`

```
    cmbMaster.DisplayMember = "Number";
    cmbMaster.ValueMember = "MasterID";
```

I don't know how get data from 2 tables for 1 combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find way for my problem

and write code for other guys maybe someone have this problem too

```
private void frmOrgChartsManage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load ComboBox Source from MasterTable
    using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        // At first assign properties DisplayMember and ValueMember.
        cmbMaster.DisplayMember = "Number";
        cmbMaster.ValueMember = "MasterID";

        // And then assign DataSource property of the cmbMaster.
        var result = (from master in db.MasterRepository.Get()
                              join number in db.tblNumRepository.Get() on master.NumID equals number.NumID 


                              select new
                              {
                                  master.MasterID,
                                  number.Number,

                              }).ToList();
                cmbMaster.DataSource = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
private void frmOrgChartsManage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Load ComboBox Source from MasterTable
            using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
            {
                // At first assign properties DisplayMember and ValueMember.
                cmbLayerName.DisplayMember = cmbNumber.Where(x => x.NumID == "NumID").Select(y => y.Number).First();
                cmbLayerName.ValueMember = "MasterID";

                // And then assign DataSource property of the cmbMaster.
                cmbMaster.DataSource = db.MasterRepository.Get();
                cmbNumber.DataSource = db.NumberRepository.Get();

            }
        }
```

You are binding to NumID, where you need to bind to Number

Comment: number is in TblNum and i Load cmbMaster.DataSource = db.MasterRepository.Get(); ( i bind data to mastertable how i can get data from numtable too )

Comment: Ali I made the changes based on your feedback. Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: i must add new combobox with this name  `cmbNumber` ?

Comment: Based on what code you have put there does not appear to be a better solution.